# How to share retrieved image from Sqlite Database to social media with bitmap?

Tags: android, android-sharing

I am new to android.I developed an android app which is based on Sqlite Database.My app everything working fine,but problem is how to share retrieved image from Sqlite Database to Social Media like  Whatsapp,Email,Facebook etc..and i don't want share image from sdcard.
Here is my source code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String IDholder;

Button Share;
DatabaseHelper dbLoginHelper;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bmp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_reports);

    Share=(Button)findViewById(R.id.report_share);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.report_image3);
    dbLoginHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    IDholder = getIntent().getStringExtra("EditID");

    Share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        shareImage();

        }
    });


}
private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmp);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    showImage();
    super.onResume();
}

private void showImage() {
    sqLiteDatabase = dbLoginHelper.getWritableDatabase();


 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.Patient_Reports + " WHERE _rid = " + IDholder + "", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

            byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Image"));
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 
            bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(), false));


        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();

    }
    }
    }
```

Image retrieved successfully from Sqlite Database and after that how to share this bitmap image to social media.above i added shareImage() but it is not working please help me.

Comment: You must have to save image on storage before share and give path of file in EXTRA_STREAM.

Comment: Ok but i don't want save on external storage ,i want to send directly bitmap retrieved from Sqlite database is it possible

Comment: That's I'm saying, it's not possible without save image. you can save image and delete later on.